# View source of file that is redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When I click a URL a redirect is taking place using `window.location`

I'm trying to see the code behind this html file but since it is redirecting I am unable to view it. How can I view the source code the redirecting file ? Can I force the browser to not execute the javascript code and instead view it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to **view-source:http://your-url-here/**

Comment: The other thing, is that if you don't know the url of the page you want, use the Developer tools panel and find the referrer of the page you are redirected to.

Comment: Doesn't work for me as of April 2019. Neither in Firefox nor in Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

You can just **curl** or **wget** on the page URL from the command line

```
curl http://page/
```

Curl does not interpret javascript, so you will get the exact HTTP response!

Comment: Or you can view headers and for multiple redirects limit the redirect like this:
`curl -iL --max-redirs 1 https://some-url.com`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [requesting the page through telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466)?

```
telnet www.serverhost.com 80
GET /directory/file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a new tab on the browser
2. Open the inspector (F12) > Network tab
3. Check "Preserve log"
4. Paste the url you want to inspect in the address bar and press Enter
5. In the Network tab you can see all the resource called and also the "original" page (you can filter by string in order to find it easly)
6. Click the original page; on the right you can see the preview of that page